# LINK : fatal error LNK1248: image size exceeds maximum allowable size (80000000)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am doing some extremely large array processing. I do a global declaration of:

```
`float array[200][1600][811];`
```

When I build my solution in MS Visual Studio 2010, I get the following error

`LINK : fatal error LNK1248: image size (F85C8000) exceeds maximum allowable size (80000000)`

Now, I am aware this amounts to about 1 GB of program memory. But this declaration worked for a declaration of `float [50][1600][811]` which amounts to 250 MB. I know the default stack size is very limited. 
There are a couple of things I have already tried. I increased the stack size in VS through Properties -> Linker -> Stack reserved size. This didnt help. I changed my executable to run in x64 mode (which is said to address upto 2GB memory!). This didnt help either.

I do not wish to do a `malloc` on the array because I know for sure I need them in my code. I had to make them global declarations so that I can avail the stack/heap memory. If I declare them inside my `Main ()`, it gives me error of memory overflow.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't (and you can't) put that on the stack. Don't even try. For all practical purposes, heap allocation is unavoidable for something of that size.

Comment: It is right time to find out what heap memory allocation is all about. Or, here is `x64` platform to feel comfortable for some time.

Comment: The first thing to ask is whether you need to use an array in the first place. You don't if most of the values remain set to the default or if you can process them in such an order that they don't all need to be in memory at the same time.

Comment: That declaration isn't going on the stack or the heap, it's going into global process memory. That's the only reason the linker is seeing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that even when you're building an x64 executable, the linker has limits more appropriate for an x86 build. Not much you can do about that.

The only solution is to allocate it from the heap. This should be usable in the same way as your original declaration.

```
typedef float partial_array[1600][811];
std::unique_ptr<partial_array> array = new partial_array[200];
```

Comment: @MarkB, not 100% sure. [Microsoft's unique_ptr documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx) mentions a partial specialization for arrays that would cover it, but I don't know if it's part of the standard and I don't know if my `typedef` defeats it.

Comment: It appears to exist outside of MS, too... but even if it didn't, you could always create your own deleter. In either case, the OP is presumably talking about a object (in the general sense) created at runtime that persists for the lifetime of the application. The host OS can always be relied upon to clean up any memory allocation when the process exits, right? Lazy, but it would suffice, surely.

Comment: @Rook If it was just leaked sure, but mixing `new` and `delete` forms is, as I recall, undefined rather than just harmless.

Comment: True. I was thinking of skipping the whole delete phase entirely. A custom non-deleting deleter would do, but it seems like a rather roundabout way to do things!

Comment: @Rook, at that point you might as well use a dumb pointer. It won't automatically delete anything either.

Comment: @MarkB since this question first came up, I have learned that `unique_ptr` works correctly with arrays per the standard. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr for example.

Answer (score 3):

If you are `malloc` adverse, you have two immediately obvious possibilties. C++11 has a nice array type which might help:

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<float, 50>, 1600>, 811> matrix;
```

Or you could consider using `std::vector` with a loop to initialise all the values correctly:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>> matrix;
matrix.reserve(50);

for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> submatrix;
    submatrix.reserve(1600);

    for (size_t j = 0; j < 1600; j++)
    {
        std::vector<float> row;
        row.resize(811);

        submatrix.push_back(row);
    }

    matrix.push_back(submatrix);
}
```