# exceeds maximum allowable size (80000000)

Tags: c, linker-errors, max

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINK : fatal error LNK1248: image size exceeds maximum allowable size (80000000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211840/link-fatal-error-lnk1248-image-size-exceeds-maximum-allowable-size-80000000)

```
#define no_cust 4000
#define no_plant 50  
#define no_sup 2000  
#define No_population 100
#define Iteration 3

struct Output2{
    long double RandomZhj[No_population];
    double Population[No_population];   
    long double result;
    long double cost_sup_to_plant;
    long double velocity[No_population];        
}Zhj[no_sup][no_plant],Whj[no_sup][no_plant],Vhj_t1[no_sup][no_plant];
```

when I run program, it shows:

> fatal error LNK1248: image size (818D4000) exceeds maximum allowable size (80000000)

I want to know how can I correct my program.

Comment: Looks like VLA abuse to me. Use dynamic allocation instead.

Comment: Let's see, the array has 100000 elements. 3 of them makes it 300000. Each struct contains at least: 8 * 300 = 2400 bytes. So total memory needed is at least 720MB.

Answer (score 7):

Don't create massive arrays like that.  Use dynamic allocation (i.e. `malloc`/`free` instead).

Comment: I did that and still getting the error

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem. Windows limits static code and data to 2GB, and you have exceeded this. Even on 64-bit Windows, no matter how much memory you have, the 2GB limit for static (non-allocatable) data remains.

The solution is to change the arrays from being declared with fixed bounds to being allocatable, and then using ALLOCATE to make them the desired size. If you are on a 64-bit system, this will allow you to have larger arrays. But if you are on a 32-bit system, you cannot go larger than 2GB.

You're trying to allocate too much static memory which the system cannot provide for you. So please make your array size smaller. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the structure is too large . Your OS limits static code and data to `80000000(2 GB)`, and you have exceeded this here.

Dynamically allocate using `malloc` in your program rather than doing this at build time.