# Total amount of static memory on VS2015 solution

Tags: visual-studio, out-of-memory

I am using VS2015 on a 64 machine, sometimes when I allocate too much static memory I get the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211840/link-fatal-error-lnk1248-image-size-exceeds-maximum-allowable-size-80000000). Can I know in advance what is the total amount of static memory allocated in a solution when I don't get an allocation error? (i.e. When the solution successfully compiled ).

Comment: Look at the .map file that the linker can produce.  It doesn't only tell you how much you used, also which variable eats the most.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/map-generate-mapfile

Comment: @HansPassant - Have produced the map file but I can't find any information about the variables whatsoever.